# scrape text from web with agility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Having real trouble locating the text from this website with the node
I've tried all sorts or xPaths inside the selectnodes brackets
 does anyone have any ideas?

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.LoadFromBrowser("https://app.box.com/s/v2l2cd1mwhemijbigv88nyfk592rjei0");
        HtmlNode[] nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@*[starts-with(local-name(),'bcpr9')]").ToArray();



        foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
            {
           textBox1.Text = item.InnerText;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only put the text from the last node into the text box as you are overwriting it each loop of the for loop. Try this:

```
textBox1.Text += item.InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still having trouble, I think the issue is with the xPath. The path that I put into SelectNodes either returns all the wrong text or gives me a null error. How do I get the numbers xPath from https://app.box.com/s/v2l2cd1mwhemijbigv88nyfk592rjei0    Thanks